# What's the difference between embedsMany and hasMany in Strongloop loopback

Tags: relationships, loopbackjs

At first sight they seem to do the same thing: define a one-to-many relation
So why would you choose one or another?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EmbedsMany - a model that embeds many instances of another model; for example, a Customer can have multiple email addresses and each email address is a complex object that contains label and address. A hasMany relation builds a one-to-many connection with another model.

EmbedsMany embeds all child objects in the same parent object,
HasMany stores child objects separately and has a property as the foreign key to reference the declaring model.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, I'm guessing this only applies for document databases like MongoDB?

Comment: @Ernie - the backend DB doesn't really matter, mysql will happily store a stringified JSON array or object in a column